# Customize Windows 7 Theme To Black

Tags: windows-7, colors, themes

I want to get a theme like this: http://djabytown.deviantart.com/art/Dark-Agility-Visual-Style-148691785

But it uses tools that can not be [downloaded](http://deepxw.blogspot.com/2008/11/universal-theme-patcher.html) any longer (and frankly I worry would not work with current versions of windows 7).

Is there a way to get a black on black theme of windows?  The "High Contrast" themes have title bars that are very distracting. (Bright Blue or Purple)

I went to [Microsoft's theme site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/themes) and it seems to be all about flashy backgrounds and bright colors.

Answer (score 0):

Vishal Gupta (owner of infamous [askvg.com](http://askvg.com)) offers an alternative for Universal Theme Patcher. Take a look at [here.](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-install-use-custom-3rd-party-themes-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/)

PS : UxStyle isn't written by Vishal Gupta. :)